# JRIを使って正規分布を描く

Tags: java, r

Rをjava上で使いたかったのでJRIを用いることでできるようにしました。
R上では正規分布のグラフは以下のようにすることで書くことができます。

```r
curve(dnorm(x,0,1),-4,4)
```

これをJava上でJRIを使って実行するのにはどうすればよろしいのでしょうか？
参考になるサイト等もあれば教えていただきたいです

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とりあえず、画像に保存する方法。必要だったらこの画像を取り出してJFrameにでも貼ってください。

```
    engine.eval("png('curve.png', 640, 480)");
    engine.eval("curve(dnorm(x,0,1),-4,4)");
    engine.eval("dev.off()");
    engine.end()
```

[image: 生成した画像です]

コメントで聞かれたので追加、org.rosuda.javaGD.GDInterfaceを実装したクラスをJRIに渡すことで、いい感じに描画するらしい。

```
    engine.eval( "Sys.setenv('JAVAGD_CLASS_NAME'='rinterface/RWindow')" )
    engine.eval( "library(JavaGD)" )
    engine.eval( "JavaGD(width=1000, height=600, ps=12)" )
```

こんな風に。[詳細はここを参照。scalaだけど。。](https://pastebin.com/b2FAV6X4)
基本Scalaでできることは同じ方法でJavaでもできますよね。

Comment: 質問なのですが、画像をパソコン内に保存せずに直接JFlameなりに張り付ける方法ってありますかね？

Comment: できるようですよ。

Comment: ごめんなさい。Scalaは全然知らないんです。。。Defがたくさん見えましたが、意味も分からなかったりmします。申し訳ないです

Comment: scalaはjavavm上で動作する言語なので、基本的にdefをメソッドとしてとらえてみれば、そんなに違和感ないと思います。暇があれば、Javaで動かしてみますね。

Comment: そうなんですね。自分でもやってみます。お暇でしたらJavaでも動かしてみていただけるととても助かります。

Comment: 全然わかりませんでした。申し訳ないです